# Google Maps V2 - Android - Get the current zoom level

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

How do I get the current zoom level as an integer on a GoogleMap.  I need to take this code from GMaps v1.1:

```
MapView mGoogleMapView; 

int zoomLevel = mGoogleMapView.getZoomLevel();
```

I am aware of the methods getMinZoomLevel() and getMaxZoomLevel() however I can't find anything in the Android GMap V2 documentation that will give the current zoom level.  Does anyone have any pointers on how to do this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Apparently this api doesn't exist in current Google Maps....

Answer (score 235, accepted):

```
GoogleMap map;
```

....

```
float zoom = map.getCameraPosition().zoom;
```

Comment: This has to be done on UI thread, or you'll get an exception!

Answer (score 47):

I think **OnCameraChangeListener** will do the trick..

```
map.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {

    private float currentZoom = -1;

    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) {
        if (position.zoom != currentZoom){
            currentZoom = position.zoom;  // here you get zoom level
        }
    }
});
```

**Update:**

From Google Play service 9.4.0 **OnCameraChangeListener** has been deprecated and it will no longer work soon.Alternately they are replaced by **OnCameraMoveStarted‌​Listener**,**OnCameraMoveListener**,**OnCameraMoveCancel‌​edListener** and **OnCameraIdleListener**.

Hence we can use **OnCameraIdleListener** here to get camera's current zoom level.

Code Sample:

```
map.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCameraIdle() {
        int zoomLevel = map.getCameraPosition().zoom;
        //use zoomLevel value..
    }
});
```

Comment: This method was deprecated.
Replaced by setOnCameraMoveStartedListener(GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener), setOnCameraMoveListener(GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener), setOnCameraMoveCanceledListener(GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveCanceledListener) and setOnCameraIdleListener(GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener).

Comment: @NaszNjokaSr., thanks for your concern. Updated accordingly.

Comment: Isn't it possible in your updated version, just to use `map.getCameraPosition().zoom` ?
Why is the implementation of a listener necessary?
And with this `onCameraIdleListener` wouldn't you get the current zoom level only when the camera goes into the idle mode?

Comment: and looks like zoom value is a float not an int.